# want to make a dnn module of time zone converter

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

i am new to dnn. i want to make a time zone converter module of dnn. will you please provide me the step by step process of making module in c#? there are many Blogs or matter on inetrnet. but that only provide the Overview Upto installing the module On dnn website. please Provide me the Write data.

Comment: You mean how to generally create a module for DNN?

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/LCTDNNModDev.aspx) tutorials helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to create a standard DNN module in C#, you can:
1) download the starterkit from http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/

2)run the starterkit to instatll the C# DNN module template
3)start your Visual Studio, select File-->New-->Project, when the "new project" popup appears,
select the "Dotnetnuke Compiled Module" template from "Web" under "Visual C#", then type the module name as the project name and select the "DesktopModules" folder of your DNN site as the project location, please refer to the following figure:

4) add your code to the project like develop a C# web application